# Jumping to function declarations in PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a class like

```
class bank
{
    public $accounts;
    public function __construct()
    {
           $accounts = new Accounts();
    }

    public function fun1()
    {
           ///some code
    }
}
```

Inside `fun1()`, I dont get the auto complete(in PHPStorm and Eclipse) feature when using

```
$this->accounts->..any function
```

But it works fine when, directly using

```
$accounts->..auto complete works fine here
```

Can we achieve the same in the first case?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Berry Langerak for rightly pointing it out.

Also, is it possible to

```
class bank
{
    public $accounts;
    public function __construct()
    {
           $this->accounts = new Accounts();
    }

    public function fun1()
    {
           ///Note changing the reference now
           $this->accounts = new OldAccounts();
           $this->accounts->..it still shows the functions of Accounts Class, can we override this setting in PHPStorm
    }
}
```

Can we override the behavior and show the functions of the new class, the reference is pointing to

Comment: Shouldn't `$accounts;` be `var $accounts;`?

Comment: Try to write valid class code first. Use `var $accounts` in PHP 4 and something like `protected $accounts` in PHP 5.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the public declaration (public)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're setting "new Accounts" to a local variable in your constructor, versus setting it to the class variable (no $this);

```
class bank
{
    public $accounts;
    public function __construct()
    {
           $this->accounts = new Accounts();
    }

    public function fun1()
    {
           $this->accounts->doStuff( );

           /* @var OldAccounts $this->accounts */
           $this->accounts = new OldAccounts;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, could you please just re-chk the question, just updated it

Comment: @Akash Changing the type of the member gets a little more involved, because PHP is a dynamic language. You can overwrite it with `/* @var OldAccounts */` though.

Comment: @Akash See my update. I don't use PHPStorm, but I suspect this will work.

Comment: thanks, but it dosent seem to work in PHPStorm, which IDE have you been using?

Comment: @Akash I use Netbeans myself.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the variable has not been documented. This will let the IDE know about the reference (line #3):

```
/* @var Accounts */
$accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you haven't defined it as a class variable. IE it should be `protected $accounts`, `public $accounts` or `private $accounts`